# Solving homogeneous linear DE of n degree using Wronski determinant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is my task:

Explain use of Wronski determinant on solving homogeneous linear DE of n degree:

$y^{(n)}=a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y$

Any idea?

Comment: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Description_of_method)  may be useful and relevant to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $ y_1, y_2,..., y_n$ are $n$ solutions of the homogenous $n$th-order linear differential equation

$ y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+ \space ... \space +a_1(x)y'+a_0(x)y = 0$

on an open interval $I$, where each $a_i(x)$ is continuous.

If Wronskian is

$ W = W(y_1, y_2,..., y_n) = 
 \begin{vmatrix}
  y_{1} & y_{2} & \cdots & y_{n} \\
  y'_{1} & y'_{2} & \cdots & y'_{n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  y_{1}^{(n-1)} & y_{2}^{(n-1)} & \cdots & y_{n}^{(n-1)} 
 \end{vmatrix} $

then there are two possible cases:

$\bullet \space \space y_1, y_2,..., y_n $ are linearly independent $\space \Longrightarrow \space W = 0$

$\bullet \space \space y_1, y_2,..., y_n$ are linearly dependent, $ \space \Longrightarrow \space W \neq 0 $

Thus either $ W = 0 $ everywhere on $I$, or $ W \neq 0 $ everywhere on $I$.